# log4j2 and ch.qos.logback.core.PropertyDefinerBase

Tags: java, logging, configuration, logback, log4j2

Logback's PropertyDefinerBase allows to use dynamic properties within logback.xml. I use this to configure a target directory for a FileAppender with values from my application config. In my case there's an enum instance that contains the value I want to use:

```
public String getPropertyValue() {return MyConfigEnum.LOGDIR.value();}
```

Relevant parts of logback.xml:

```
<fileNamePattern>${logdir}/test.log</fileNamePattern>
```

... and:

```
<define name="logdir" class="com.example.MyLogdirDefiner" />
```

This idiom is now needed for log4j **2**. How can I apply the value of MyConfigEnum.LOGDIR in a log4j2.xml?

I don't want to set a property upon application start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j2 also lets you define new properties in the configuration file.

Details are in the Configuration > Property Substitution section of the manual: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

Comment: Thanks, accepting your answer. Obviously there's no one-to-one analogy in Log4j. I now implemented an own StrLookup like the SystemPropertiesLookup. These Lookups are auto-registered by Log4j's Interpolator upon start, compare: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html